# Creating a full-stack heroku app with multiple workers on a hobby dyno

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

I have a heroku hobby dyno and I am creating an app that would need to perform a few tasks:

1. Deploy a front-end website
2. Run a scheduled background task to make an API request and update a database (DynamoDB)
3. Host an API to connect the front-end with the database

From my understanding heroku *always* starts up a web instance (the front-end) and allows the possibility to create multiple workers, one for the API and one for the scheduled job.

I was unclear from their documentation if these 3 separate node apps would run on one dyno (assuming I scaled each of them to one instance) or if I would require multiple dynos to run them all.

Note: This is a hobby project so I am trying to keep the costs as low as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hobby Dyno and hobby Dyno allows up to 10 different processes, each process running on a single hobby Dyno instance!

You should be fine running each of them in its own hobby dyno assuming you do not have a lot of users concurrently reaching the front end or if you do not have a long-running intensive process!

Note that all of them will share the same CPU (up to 512 MB) and there will be a 50 concurrent requests limit!

All of these is documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types)

You can have all the three services you have mentioned in one single node project!

Your `Procfile` will have an entry for the web process and background worker!

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot!  

I am just confused about your statement about 50 concurrent requests. The link you mentioned states a limitation of `Up to 50 concurrent one-off hobby dynos`. That sounds like the scheduler can only schedule 50 tasks to execute at once _not_ that the jobs can only make a combined of 50 requests at one time.  

If you are correct and the total requests at once is 50 does that mean I cannot have more than 50 people using my app assuming there were no background api requests? That sounds like a very strict limitation to me.

Comment: Note that it is more than 50 requests hitting the front-end app simultaneously! This will be very rare I believe to have 50 users reaching the app at the same time!